# What is the meaning of "Nur um"

Tags: english-to-german, preposition, grammaticality

I am translating a little text of mine, and I used Google Translate to know parts that I did not know, for example, **Just to see the sun**. I don't/didn't know **Just** in this context in german, then I used Google Translate, and it told **Nur um die Sonne zu sehen**, my question is why **um** after **nur**?

Resumed: **Nur um die Sonne zu sehen**, why the **um** after the **nur** in this sentence?

Comment: These are two independent words. Nur=just (or only), um=to (to see...). The words' meanings can be compared to the english phrase. Can you explain your problem in more details?

Comment: The "um" has the same purpose in the sentence (in this context) that the optional phrase "in order" would do in English. "Just [in order] to see the sun". Or "I went outside [in order] to see the sun".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word "um" in this context introduces the reason why something is done. As such it is necessary, but you could leave out "nur": "**Um die Sonne zu sehen**, ging ich hinaus" means "I went outside **to see the sun**".

The word "nur" is often a correct translation for "just" (in the sense of only). Together with "um" it is used when the effort seems too high compared to the result. "**Nur** um die Sonne zu sehen, ging ich auf den Berg." means "I climbed the mountain **just** to see the sun."